# In VBA, how to enumerate named range entries according to their position on the worksheet

Tags: sorting, listbox, excel, named-ranges, vba

I have named ranges arranged one under another in a worksheet.

In the Initialize Event of a userform (that contains a listbox), I add entries to the listbox when each entry is a name of one named range.

By now I managed to load the list up with entries according to the alphabetic order of the named ranges, so the names starting with 'a' are at the top of the list and 'z' at the bottom.

I want the entries to be at the order they appear in the worksheet, so the named range appearing closer to A1 will appear at the top of the list, and named range under A1 will be the second entry and so on up to the last named range in the worksheet (at the bottom of the worksheet) which of course will be the last entry.

Can anyone find an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim nLoop As Name

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(, 1).Cells
            For Each nLoop In ThisWorkbook.Names
                If Not Intersect(Range(nLoop.RefersTo), Range(rCell.Address)) Is Nothing Then
                    If Not .Exists(nLoop.Name) Then
                        Me.ListBox1.AddItem nLoop.Name
                        .Add (nLoop.Name), Nothing
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an elegant solution but it is a simple solution.

The code below assumes that the range names are in Cells A1, A2, A3, etc. of Sheet2 and that the list is terminated by a blank cell.  It also assumes there is nothing in columns B, C, etc.  You will have to adjust the code for the true situation.

```
Sub GetNameDetails()

  Dim Inx As Integer
  Dim NameCrnt As String
  Dim Pos As Integer
  Dim RangeCrnt As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Integer

  RowCrnt = 1
  With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Do While True
      ' This loop is repeated for every cell in column A until it
      ' encounters a blank cell 
      NameCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value
      If NameCrnt = "" Then Exit Do
      For Inx = 1 To Names.Count
        ' This matches the names in Sheet 2 with the named ranges.
        ' Names that cannot be found in the Names collection are ignored. 
        If Names(Inx).Name = NameCrnt Then
          RangeCrnt = Names(Inx).RefersTo          ' Extract full address of range 
          RangeCrnt = Mid(RangeCrnt, 2)            ' Discard =
          RangeCrnt = Replace(RangeCrnt, "$", "")  ' Remove $s
          Pos = InStr(RangeCrnt, "!")
          ' Save sheet name
          .Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value = Mid(RangeCrnt, 1, Pos - 1)
          RangeCrnt = Mid(RangeCrnt, Pos + 1)      ' Discard sheet name
          .Cells(RowCrnt, 3).Value = RangeCrnt     ' Save full address of range
          Pos = InStr(RangeCrnt, ":")
          If Pos <> 0 Then
            RangeCrnt = Mid(RangeCrnt, 1, Pos - 1) ' Discard end of range if any
          End If
          .Cells(RowCrnt, 4).Value = .Range(RangeCrnt).Row
          .Cells(RowCrnt, 5).Value = .Range(RangeCrnt).Column
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

The result is a table of five columns:

```
Col 1 = Range name  (unchanged)
Col 2 = Sheet name
Col 3 = Range
Col 4 = Top row of range
Col 5 = Left column of range
```

After sorting by columns 4 and 5, the table will be in sequence you seek.

Comment: FWIW: Instead of ``Do While True``, ``Do While VarType(.Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value) <> vbEmpty`` might be safer.

Comment: Good point.  I tend not to worry about safety for code that will be run by the author.  Perhaps it is time I started considering safety all the time.

Comment: Just out of interest, what does Crnt mean?

Comment: @Reafidy It's an abbreviation for "current".